# Apache2 mod_log_config and milliseconds not working on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, ubuntu-12.04

I cannot setup millisecond nor microsecond logging format as timestamp on my Apache2 default installation running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTE.
I've changed log format in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf config file to look like:

```
LogFormat "%{msec}t %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

but as a result I see log output:

```
msec 192.168.19.99 - - [21/Mar/2013:15:16:11 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"
```

mod_log_config should be installed, see output

```
$ apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  worker.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

Has anyone idea why i cannot see millisecond in my output log ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) for this, check which version do you have:

```
apache2 -v
```

I believe Ubuntu 12.04 has httpd-2.2.22. 3rd party packages for Apache-2.4 are available if you don't want to compile it yourself, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/153153/apache-2-4-2-ppa-or-normal-pkg-release-date .